# Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 enable Hibernate

Tags: gnome

Is there a way to enable hibernate in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 ?
I can do it manually via the terminal but would like to add to power off option if possible.
Thanks in advance for any help in this matter,
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Install Tweak Tool - either via Ubuntu Software Center or:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After installing open it. In Tweak Tool's **Shell** section options choose **Hibernate** at **Power button action**.